# Finding the mean and variance for pmf $P(X_i = x)=-\theta^x/x\log(1-\theta)$?

Tags: self-study, exponential-family

I'd like to verify that my working/thinking is correct. This is a problem from Keener's book, but the answer isn't provided.

Let $X$ have distribution $P(X = x)=-\theta^x/x\log(1-\theta)$ for $x=1,2,\dots $. The problem asks to find the mean and variance of $X$.

At first I tried to solve $\sum x P(X=x)$, however I think the point is to solve it using properties of exponential-family distributions. Specifically, we can write the PMF as:

$$P(X=x) = \exp \left(x \log(-\theta) - \log (x) - \log \log (1-\theta)   \right)$$

So that $X$ comes from an exponential distribution with complete sufficient statistic $T(X) = X$ and canonical parameter $\eta = \log (-\theta)$. Using this, we have $\theta = -e^\eta$ and so the normalising constant can be written

$$A(\eta) = \log \log (1-\theta(\eta)) = \log \log (1+e^\eta)$$

From here, I believe the mean and variance of $X=T(X)$ are then given by:

$$E[X] = \frac{\partial A(\eta)}{\partial \eta}$$

$$Var(X) = \frac{\partial^2 A(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}$$

Is this a correct understanding of the problem?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks! I have never heard of that distribution.

Comment: The expression after *write the PMS as:* is wrong. I would write $\log P(X = x) = x \log \theta - \log x + \log[ - \log(1 - \theta)]$. The parameter $\theta$ must be such that $0 < \theta < 1$.

Comment: This formula does not define a valid pmf (or even a density).  It gives negative values when $x$ is negative, for instance, showing that it *must* be accompanied by a statement of the domains of both $x$ and $\theta.$ Even if we leap to big assumptions, such as that $x$ is intended to be a nonnegative integer, the division by $x$ is still problematic at $x=0,$ raising the possibility that a very special set of possible values of $x$ is intended: what is it??

Comment: @whuber it says $x=1,2,\dots$ sorry I forgot to include that

Comment: Thank you.  Because $(\theta^x)_{x=1,2,\ldots}$ is a geometric series, it sums to $\theta/(1-\theta).$  Multiplying by $\theta$ and differentiating term-by-term shows $x\theta^x$ sums to $\theta/(1-\theta)^2.$ Use these results to find $E[X]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ directly and compare them to the Exponential-family solution to answer your question.